# Why is Python code writing strange things?

Tags: python, file, output

I wrote a code that should take a file written in English and print it but instead it returned some strange things. I posted the code and an image of the output. What should i do in order to solve the problem?

```
f = open("Introduction-first-part.docx")
print(f.read())
```

[image: output]

Comment: That is happening because the file is in `docx` format. Try converting it to plain text and reading it instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading in a `.txt` file instead. `.docx` is a microsoft word format which does not store text in plaintext which means when you read it you will not get 'english'. It stores things like fonts, spacing, size, and a lot of other information aside form just the contents of the file.

Copy your text out into a different format if you want to read it with python is probably the easiest way.

Comment: It's a zipped collection of mostly XML files. Since it's compressed, there's very little plain text in there.